# Scaling objects with constant wall thickness for 3D printing

Tags: 3d-printing

I am using blender to create stl files for 3d printing. Let's say I create a shell for a model railroad car. Since 1/87th is the most common scale I make the walls of the shell just thick enough to make it rigid in 1/87 scale. Now if I want to print the same shell in a larger scale, say 1/48 the wall thickness will nearly double and it will waste material printing walls that are thicker than needed. If I want to print in 1/160 the printing may fail because the wall thickness falls below the minimum the printer will support. Any ideas?

--> I have posted this to the 3D printing forum

Comment: I think http://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/ suits your question better. Also it could help if you make it a bit easier for understanding, e.g. it's unclear what is the exact problem - searching for correct scale of the mesh prior to creating or scaling existing mesh etc.

Comment: The question is how to scale an existing mesh without changing the thickness of the walls.

Comment: It is not related to 7503/...  Changing the exporter scale results in thicker or thinner walls in the final printed object, which is exactly the problem I am trying to avoid.

Comment: Well, it could be related if it worked as I thought; now I know it doesn't. I'm not aware of any way to do that; Blender will scale proportionally if using Scale. Maybe the easiest way will be to delete inside parts and recreate them with Solidify.

Comment: The closest thing I can think of is a Maintain Volume constraint. I don't know too much about it but it seems to be able to help.

Comment: Yes I think that solidify modifier is exactly what I need here.